# During iOS app review, can we have testers launch the app from a URL?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Our app will respond to a URL to configure the app differently.  We do that for testing changes before we are ready for our users to see that after publishing.  Will Apple follow our instructions to test the app from a URL or will they insist that they start the app from the icon like most users?

Comment: Interesting one, I would guess they will open the app via the icon. Perhaps you need to add an information page to tell users they need to do something else first ?

Comment: We would have backend changes that once they approve it, the app would change for everyone.  This is a way for them to see how it will be configured before we make that available to everyone.  Our thoughts are to explain the URL to use in the Notes section in the itunes connect metadata for the app, where we have that 4000 characters of internal notes to the tester.

Comment: I think, you can enter these instruction in iTunesConnect and the apple tester will try this.

**But** they will also check if you app works without the configuration link.

Comment: I agree with Dominik.  They may try the app with the link, but they will almost certainly try it without the link.  As long as the app doesn't violate any of the guidelines in both cases, you should be fine.  If the new version of the app crashes if you launch it without using the url, you will get rejected.

Comment: It is not a problem to test from starting the app but they will not see the new features and the test username may not have a successful login.

Comment: Has anyone ever tried this?